# Python: Reading tdms files using Python npTDMS and creating a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, labview

I'm able to read a labview .tdms file using Python npTDMS package, could read metadata and sample data for groups and channels as well.
However, the file has timestamp values with year '9999'. Hence getting the following error while converting to a pandas dataframe:

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp:.

I went through the documentation in:
https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#nptdms.TdmsFile.as_dataframe; however, couldn't find an option to deal with this data situation.

Tried passing errors='coerce' while calling as.dataframe() didn't work either. Any pointers or directions to read the .tdms file to a pandas dataframe, with this data situation, would be very helpful.

Changing the data at the source is not an option.

Code snippet to read tdms file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td

tdms_file = td.read(<tdms file name>)
tdms_file_df = tdms_file.as_dataframe()
```

[Error while creating a pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paoeK.png)